# cant create file for livenessProbe and redinessProbe

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-health-check

hy folks

I'm currently trying to set up the livenessProbe and readinessProbe. 
After starting the container I ask to create an empty file *touch /tmp/healthy*.

However i don't know why it can't create it. 
I looked at the kubernet site and examples on the internet and from what I could see everything seems correct.

The liveness send me back this answear 
**Liveness probe failed: cat: can't open '/tmp/healthy': No such file or directory**

Thank you for your help

https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/5c79f7f96e4a6deb7b79753bde688663

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write /bin/sh in commad and -c touch /tmp/healthy in args fields as below:

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "touch /tmp/healthy"]
```

Comment: Gosh, I was searching for this for hours... Can't figure why my python cmd could not find my file...

Answer (score 1):

Please, correct the value of imagePullPolicy in the YAML, its value should be **Always** not allways. Might be this is the issue that's why /tmp/healthy not getting created.

[Recheck you YAML with kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-command)